# How controller extension is updating record

Tags: apex, visualforce

Apex Page :

```
 <apex:page standardController="account" extensions="RandomWorkSpace_Ext_Cntrl" >
    <!—note the extensions attribute above -->
      <apex:sectionHeader title="Account Edit" subtitle="{!account.name}" />
      <apex:pageMessages />  
      <apex:form>
        <apex:pageBlock title="Account Edit" mode="edit" >
          <apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}" />
            <!-- add a new button to call our genericPhone() method -->
            <apex:commandButton value="Generic Phone" action="{!genericPhone}" />
            <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!cancel}" />
          </apex:pageBlockButtons>
          <apex:pageBlockSection title="Account Info" columns="3" >
            <apex:inputField value="{!account.name}" />
            <apex:inputField value="{!account.phone}" />
          </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
      </apex:form>
    </apex:page>
```

Extension :

```
public class RandomWorkSpace_Ext_Cntrl {

    public sObject myRecord;
    public ApexPages.StandardController std;
    public RandomWorkSpace_Ext_Cntrl(ApexPages.StandardController std){
        this.std = std;
        myRecord = std.getRecord();

    }


      public void genericPhone(){
        //These 3 sObjects have a field named 'phone'
        if ( myRecord instanceof Account ||
        myRecord instanceof Contact || 
        myRecord instanceof Lead 
        ){
          myRecord.put('phone','(818) 555-1212');
        }
        }
}
```

**In the extension method genericPhone(), there was no update statement called upon sObject. So how the extension is able to update the record. What is the underlying concept for this ?**

Comment: This method cannot perform any updates, as you have noted. Are you sure it's not just updated once you click the `save` button?

Comment: @AdrianLarson It's almost as though his method extends `phone` for any of the 3 objects it's written for since it's an instance method.  It isn't written to extend Account per se even though he declares it that way on his page "generically" (wrong extension class name).

Comment: you are using standardcontroller save method

Comment: the page refers to an extension class that is different than your posted class.  As an aside, action methods should generally be named verb-like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`genericPhone` doesn't save the change to the database. After calling, but before you click save, the in-memory representation is updated, but the change isn't persisted until save is called.

Comment: Yes @Sfdcfox, unless not clicked on save the changes are not saved. Only the phone value changes to the given value after clicking on genricPhone button but its not committed to the database unless save is clicked.